# iOS 7 Nav Bar SKStoreProductViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, ios7

In iOS 6, SKStoreProductViewController was introduced to show iTunes Store items in apps, so the user would not have to leave the app to view them.

So far, I have not found a way to customize the navigation bar of this view controller. In iOS 6, it is black with grey writing, and in iOS 7, it is white with black writing.

Is there any way to change the navigation bar's tint color? (In iOS 6 & iOS 7)

Thanks.

Comment: I can not see how this question would be off-topic or in any way showing too little research effort -> no reason for downvote or close?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not the nicest solution but you can use UINavigationBar's UIAppearance method to set the colour just before you show it:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];

SKStoreProductViewController *storeProductViewController = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
[storeProductViewController setDelegate:self];
[self presentViewController:storeProductViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And then in the SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate method, change it back to whatever it was previously...

```
-(void)productViewControllerDidFinish:(SKStoreProductViewController *)viewController {
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Works for me.

Comment: Does this change the color of the bar or the color of the buttons on the bar? (It is only changing the button color for me)

Comment: @JakeChasan My apologies, misunderstood the question. The problem I was experiencing, which is why I found my way to this question, was that I was getting a white nav bar with white buttons.

Comment: This does not work for me on iOS 7; not sure about 6.  The issue does not exist in iOS 8 however as the `SKStoreProductViewController` seems to actually okay the UIAppearance settings.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, no.  `SKStoreProductViewController` is a [remote view controller](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/10/remote-view-controllers-in-ios-6/), meaning its view is completely owned by another process and inaccessible programatically.

This can be confirmed by looking at the recursive description of the controller's view:

```
<UIView: 0x8d48da0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); layer = <CALayer: 0x8d48d70>>
   | <_UISizeTrackingView: 0x9b53700; frame = (0 0; 320 480); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x9b53770>>
   |    | <_UIRemoteView: 0x9b51d70; frame = (0 0; 320 480); transform = [0.5, -0, 0, 0.5, -0, 0]; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayerHost: 0x9b55ae0>>
```

The `_UIRemoteView` indicates that the contents of the view is hosted in another process.

Comment: What a mess. If you've set the [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor someColor]]; in your app, it does use that color in the SKStoreProductViewController to override the default even tho it's a "remote view controller". However, setting the [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor anotherColor]];  has no effect on the SKStoreProductViewController.  OTOH, the bar tint works fine in the MFMailComposeViewController, but you need to use [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] to change the button color.  :(

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem inside Appirater rateApp function, I fixed it this way:

```
    //Use the in-app StoreKit view if available (iOS 6) and imported. This works in the simulator.
    if (!_openInAppStore && NSStringFromClass([SKStoreProductViewController class]) != nil) {

        SKStoreProductViewController *storeViewController = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
        storeViewController.delegate = self.sharedInstance;

        NSNumber *appId = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:_appId.integerValue];
        [storeViewController loadProductWithParameters:@{SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier:appId} completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error) {
            [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

            id <AppiraterDelegate> delegate = self.sharedInstance.delegate;
            if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(appiraterWillPresentModalView:animated:)]) {
                [delegate appiraterWillPresentModalView:self.sharedInstance animated:_usesAnimation];
            }


            [[self getRootViewController] presentViewController:storeViewController animated:_usesAnimation completion:^{
                [self setModalOpen:YES];
                //Temporarily use a black status bar to match the StoreKit view.
                [self setStatusBarStyle:[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle];
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:_usesAnimation];

            }];

        }];
    //Use the standard openUrl method if StoreKit is unavailable.
    } else { (...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't customize the bar's color, but its default colors look fine.  I found that my UIAppearance settings were changing the text color.

Here's a SKStoreProductViewController subclass that sets the bar text color to default, then restores your UIAppearance settings on dismiss.  Useful if you're presenting from multiple places in your code.

```
@interface GBStoreProductViewController ()
{
    UIColor *navBarTintColor;
    NSDictionary *navBarTitleTextAttributes;
}

@end

@implementation GBStoreProductViewController

- (id)init
{
    UIColor *tintColor = [[UINavigationBar appearance] tintColor];
    NSDictionary *titleTextAttributes = [[UINavigationBar appearance] titleTextAttributes];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:nil];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:nil];
    if (self = [super init]) {
        navBarTintColor = tintColor;
        navBarTitleTextAttributes = titleTextAttributes;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:navBarTintColor];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:navBarTitleTextAttributes];
}

@end
```

Credits to Kiran Panesar for the technique.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well, and the answers given for the `appearance` code wasn't working for me. I found that this is what fixed it, because I had changed my app-wide `window.tintColor` in the `appDelegate` earlier:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].tintColor = nil;
```