# SKStoreProductViewController title color

Tags: ios7, storekit, uiappearance

How do you change the title color and/or bar tint color in a SKStoreProductViewController?

I'm using the appearance API to set navigation bars to a dark color and the text to white.  It changes the title color but not the bar tint color in my SKStoreProductViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.  At least not on iOS 7.  On iOS 6 you can use the `UIAppearance` protocol and the SKSPVC will pick up the appearance you set on the `UINavigationBar`.

As noted on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18839783/697664), the SKSPVC is a [remote view controller](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/10/remote-view-controllers-in-ios-6/) so it's inaccesible programmatically, meaning that you can't set it's appearance directly (or indirectly?).

Answer (score 0):

Do the following to avoid the **SKStoreProductViewController** to take over a tintColor of value WHITE:

```
 #define kCOLOR_NON_WHITE_COLOR [UIColor darkGrayColor]

 // CHANGE ALL TINTING BEFORE WE CREATE An INSTANCE OF THIS BROKEN PIECE
[UIWindow appearance].tintColor = kCOLOR_NON_WHITE_COLOR;
[UIView appearance].tintColor = kCOLOR_NON_WHITE_COLOR;
[UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = kCOLOR_NON_WHITE_COLOR;
[UIBarButtonItem appearance].tintColor = kCOLOR_NON_WHITE_COLOR;

// NOW CREATE THE THING
SKStoreProductViewController *controller = [[[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
```

This draws all the UIBarButtonItems and the UISegmentedControls in this controller in the defined color AFAIK and thus makes the controller more like your apps design.

**IMPORTANT:** Just **do not forget(!!!)** to change all the tinting back after you dismissed this controller, otherwise fresh created views in your app might take over the enforced tinting.

**UPDATE:** As you might already have found out the following to manipulate the appearance does **not** work:

```
[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[SKStoreProductViewController class], nil]
```

This fix is for iOS 7 & 8 on iOS 6 you have different issues. =)